# No puedo hacer un return de una funcion desde un modulo, Python

Tags: python, funciones

estoy haciendo un programa simple para probar algunas cosas.
He creado un modulo para que las cosas sean mas sencillas de organizar, el problema es que en algún punto de mi código quiero que retorne la función principal y no funciona.

Cabe aclarar que esto ya lo hice en un proyecto anterior de Python 3.9.4, la version mas reciente y funciona perfectamente, Pero en este no.

Este es mi main.py :

```
import terminalcore


def thread():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    terminalcore.command_thread()

thread()
```

y este es mi modulo:

```
 t_prefix = 'H4'
    tp_text = '>>>'
    def command_thread():
            prefix, command = input(tp_text).split(" ")
            if prefix == t_prefix:
                print('H4')
                if command == 'TEST':
                        name, password = input(tp_text).split(" ")
            else:
                return thread()
```

Si prefix no se cumple quiero que me retorne una funcion a main.py, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
 File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    thread()
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\main.py", line 6, in thread
    terminalcore.command_thread()
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\terminalcore.py", line 11, in command_thread
    return thread()
NameError: name 'thread' is not defined
```

Tambien intente poner `from main import thread` pero me tiro otro error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import terminalcore
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\terminalcore.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import thread
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    thread()
  File "p:\Phyton Projects\ArgumentsTest\main.py", line 6, in thread
    terminalcore.command_thread()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'terminalcore' 
has no attribute 'command_thread' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Esta es la estructura que tengo de mis archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería que me ayudaran.

Comment: te has acordado de importar `thread`? algo asi como `from main import thread`

Comment: Si, lo he intentado de todas las formas posibles para importar módulos, además en otro proyecto usando exactamente lo mismo me funcionaba.

Comment: Deberías entonces editar tu pregunta y poner la estructura de archivos que tienes y la forma en que has importado la función thread, que creo que va a ser ese el problema.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, ahí puse la estructura de mis archivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código del módulo:

```
t_prefix = 'H4'
tp_text = '>>>'
def command_thread():
    prefix, command = input(tp_text).split(" ")
    if prefix == t_prefix:
        print('H4')
        if command == 'TEST':
            name, password = input(tp_text).split(" ")
    else:
        import main
        return main.thread()
```

El error `NameError: name 'thread' is not defined` se debe en este caso a que falta importar el módulo que contiene la función `thread()`.

Para solucionarlo, incluye `import main` antes de llamar a la función. Si se incluye en la primera línea se produce un "circular import". [Más información (en inglés)](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/)

El código de `main.py` está correcto, salvo que podrías importar `terminalcore` como `tc`:

```
import terminalcore as tc

def thread():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    tc.command_thread()

thread()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.